# Django: Highlight Table Row when user is found

Tags: javascript, python, django

I've got two models (participant, holder) which have the same fields: `first_name`, `last_name` and `date_of_birth`

In the detail view of my participant Model I check if those fields are the same as in my holder model:

```
for holder in Holder.objects.all():
    if participant.last_name == holder.last_name and participant.first_name == holder.first_name and participant.date_of_birth == holder.date_of_birth:
        has_item = True
```

and then return that with a `render_to_response`

```
return self.render_to_response({
        'has_item': has_item,
    })
```

And in my HTML I've got then this:

```
<td>{% if has_item %}<a href="{% url 'vouchers:holders' %}">Voucher(s) found</a> {% else %}No voucher found{% endif %}</td>
```

This links the user from the detail view of my participant to my ListView of my Vouchers with all Holders listed in a table. Now my question would be, when redirecting the user to this List, is it possible to somehow highlight the exact user that was found having the vouchers?

So for example if `John Doe` has a voucher, show the link in his profile, which redirects him to the list of all holders and highlights every row where his `FirstName`, `Lastname` and `Date of birth` is the same.

Is that possible with maybe using JavaScript?

Comment: You should show your models. The way you appear to have done things seems very strange - there should be a foreign key from participant to holder (or vice versa), rather than matching first and last names.

Comment: Hold on, you filter *manually* your database? Don't do that! It is terribly inefficient. A database has no only closer access to the data, it can also implement indices that make lookups several magnitudes faster.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I know that using the PK/FK would be better but right now matching the name and age is enough for my cause :) I'll update my models

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not that skilled with django, so I thought that would be a good way to do so, is there a better way?

Comment: What about `has_item = Holder.objects.filter(last_name=participant.last_name, first_name=participant.first_name, date_of_birth=participant.date_of_birth).exists()`. So a *one liner* that will ask the database if `Holder` exists.

Comment: That being said, I really advise you to "*normalize*" the database first, and thus introduce foreign keys. RIght now it is not only probable inelegant, but also inefficient, and with data duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you do, you should not be iterating through all objects to find matches. At the very least ask the db to do it:

```
try:
    matching_holder = Holder.objects.get(first_name=participant.first_name, last_name=participant.last_name, date_of_birth=participant.date_of_birth)
except Holder.DoesNotExist:
    matching_holder = None
```

now you can use `matching_holder` in your template.

But as I say, you should not be doing this at all, you should use a foreign key or other relationship field.